Why is a Hyphen Used in 'Mid-May' but Not in 'Early October'?
I'm trying to understand the rules for hyphenation in compound time expressions. Specifically, I noticed that "mid-May" is commonly hyphenated, while "early October" is not.
Mid-May: The hyphen is used between "mid" and "May" to indicate the middle of May.
Early October: There is no hyphen between "early" and "October" to indicate the beginning of October.
Could someone explain why "mid-May" requires a hyphen but "early October" does not? Are there specific grammatical rules or guidelines that determine when to use a hyphen in such cases?

early October, late October, mid-October

"mid" is not generally considered to be a "word" in this usage, but a prefix.  Etymonline notes that while "mid" was used as a word in Old English (700+ years ago) in modern English it came to be used in combination with other words  "mid-air" and with times like "mid-May".
You do sometimes see "mid" being used as a word, as a shortening of "amid", or in teen slang (meaning "fairly good")
"Early" is a word and an adjective, so no hyphen is expected.
